# Is it possible to get user sessions when using jwt auth?

Tags: authorization, jwt

Applications like "telegram" have an "active sessions" feature, where you can see and kill sessions of current user. It is not a problem to make similar feature when using session and cookies to store user sessions, but how to make it with jwt?

The server doesnt store any information about jwt so cannot even get a list of active sessions. I was thinking about storing additional information in a database when user log in, so we can get data like device name, type etc., and store access token as well. Then when user wants to kill a particular session, somehow invalidate needed access token.

What is a correct approach to make this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JWT is self-contained  and does not need server sessions, but in some cases is useful to maintain some information on server about issued and active token.

For example to set a blacklist of revoked tokens after changing user credentials, permissions or simply a logout ( you can not fully trust in client removing their data). It is not needed to store the full token, just assign an unique identifier. And only keep trace of token until expiration time.

Note also in your use case that tokens can be renewed during the user interaction, so any data related to user should be attached to the new token. If your tokens have long expiration time, persistente will be needed

I would not call ' session ' because it can lead to confusion with the traditional approach